# Groups with Same Number Of Elements and Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Say I have a finite group and I tell you how many elements and how many subgroups it has. Do you now know what group it is? Or could two groups which are not isomorphic to each other have the same amount of elements and subgroups? In other words, does the amount of elements and subgroups of a group define it completely? It is interesting because if I give you just the number of elements there are several possibilities and if I give you the number of subgroups also but perhaps both combined are enough to define the group.

Comment: $A_4$ and $C_6 \times C_2$ both have $10$ subgroups.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No finite list of numerical inariants is sufficient to classify finite groups up to isomorphism (as far as anyone knows).

Subgroups of groups of order 16 are tabulated [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_groups_of_order_16). Note that groups 2 and 4 both have 15 subgroups: 3 of order 2, 6 cyclic of order 4, 1 Klein-4 group, 3 of type $C_4\oplus C_2$ (and the one element group, and the whole group). So, not just the same number of subgroup, the same number of each type of (proper) subgroup. Similarly for groups 5 and 6.

Comment: Is there a precise definition of "numerical invariant" here? (I'd love to see a theorem to this effect!)

Comment: Noah, I'm confident that the group theorists of the world have come up with a precise definition of "numerical invariant", but the best I can come up with on my own is "a function that assigns a number to each isomorphism class of groups". I don't think there is a theorem (yet) that no finite list of numerical invariants suffices – I think the same is true for classifying finite graphs, maybe also for knots – it's just that no one has found a finite list, and no one expects there to be one. But I'm well out of my area of expertise here.

Comment: Well, with that definition a single invariant suffices since we can simply code the isomorphism type of a finite group by a finite sequence of numbers (and then code that sequence as a single number). But of course that's not going to be "structurally well-behaved."